# Json Mapping using Restkit v0.20

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, restkit

i am able to send request correctly but after receiving response i get

```
response.body ={"status":"success","loginToken":"xxxxyyyzzz"}
```

but with an error saying

```
 It Failed: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors     
match the response loaded." UserInfo=0x2b55b0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.71    
/firstyii/index.php?r=site/login, NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the 
URL 'http://192.168.1.71/firstyii/index.php?r=site/login', which failed to match all (1) 
response descriptors:

<RKResponseDescriptor: 0x2a5860 baseURL=http://192.168.1.71 pathPattern=/firstyii
/index.php?r=site/login statusCodes=200-299> failed to match: response path '/firstyii
/index.php?r=site/login' did not match the path pattern '/firstyii/index.php?r=site/login'., 
NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.71/firstyii/index.php?r=site/login, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x2b6070 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths 
searched."}
```

LoginResponse.h

```
@interface LoginResponse : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *loginToken;

+(RKObjectMapping*)defineLoginResponseMapping;

@end
```

LoginResponse.m

```
#import "LoginResponse.h"


@implementation LoginResponse

@synthesize loginToken;

@synthesize status;




+(RKObjectMapping*)defineLoginResponseMapping   {

RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LoginResponse class]];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"status":   @"status",
 @"loginToken":   @"loginToken",
  }];


return mapping;

}

@end
```

Code in LoginManager.m

```
-(void)LoginWithUserName:(NSString *)username password:(NSString*)password {

LoginRequest *dataObject = [[LoginRequest alloc] init];
[dataObject setUsername:username];
[dataObject setPassword:password];



   NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.71"];

AFHTTPClient * client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];
  [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];




[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] 
forMIMEType:@"application/json"];


RKObjectMapping *requestMapping =  [[LoginRequest defineLoginRequestMapping] inverseMapping];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor: [RKRequestDescriptor   
  requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[LoginRequest class] rootKeyPath:nil 
 ]];
// what to print
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("Restkit/Network", RKLogLevelDebug);

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [LoginResponse defineLoginResponseMapping];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor 
responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping pathPattern:@"/firstyii/index.php?r=site/login" 
keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];


 [objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType: RKMIMETypeJSON];

  [objectManager postObject:dataObject path:@"/firstyii/index.php?r=site/login" 
parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult array]);

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"It Failed: %@", error);

}];
}
```

i think that the code used above is to map response with array ,
so i need code to map simple json like this one response.body={"status":"success","loginToken":"logingngngnnggngngae"}

Comment: shouldn't you read the mapped object from mappingResult ? where did you get the response.body from ?

Comment: should i explicitly write two response classes, one for each key ie: a class for status and another one for loginToken?
and then in response descriptor set keypath to status/login token, and add two response descriptors?

Comment: assuming you are reading the response as mentioned in the first line of your question . all you have to do is use the built in JSON parser or any other json parser to get the response on the form of NSDictionaries and NSarrays

Comment: you can, you are just doing it wrong https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#reading-gists a tutorial from the library wiki on Github on how to use object mapping

Comment: did you try the tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such responses are to be mapped using pathpattern , non keyvalue mapping mentioned at  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping.

I was using pathPattern having "?" in it , hence it was not matching properly.
,also path pattern shouldnot have "/" at beginning.
the above code works fine if i change the pathPattern to  pathPattern:@"site/login"
,and postObject to postObject:@"site/login"
and ofcourse changed the baseurl = @"http://json.xxxxxxx.xxxxx:8179/jsonresponse/index.php" so that there are not special charaters in it.